# How to understand a syntax error in a three bodies problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a Python code to represent a three body problem: the issue comes forth when the gravity formula sets in: it says 'invalid syntax'. Here is the snippet of the code...

```
from pylab import *
"""
orbita vV variable tau
"""
Tmax=2.2; GM=4*pi**2
GMg=4*pi**2*9.54e-4; GMt=4*pi**2*3.015e-6          


x=1; y=0.; xg=5,26; yg=0; vx=0.; vy=pi
r=sqrt(x**2+y**2)   
rgt=sqrt((xg-x)**2+(yg-y)**2     
Fx=-GM*x/r**3; Fy = -GM*y/r**3                              
Fgtx=-GMg*(xg-x)/rgt**3; Fgty =-GMg*(yg-y)/rgt**3  

aa=0.1
v=abs(sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2))
a=abs(sqrt(Fx**2 + Fy**2)+abs(sqrt(Fgtx**2 + Fgty**2))
tau=(-v + sqrt(v**2 + 2*a*aa*abs(r)))/a
```

```
File "<ipython-input-1-54f667811fbf>", line 21
tau=(-v + sqrt(v**2 + 2*a*aa*abs(r)))/a   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The preceding line `a=abs(....` lacks a closing parenthesis. Probably just after `Fy**2`.

Comment: a=abs(sqrt(Fx**2 + Fy**2)+abs(sqrt(Fgtx**2 + Fgty**2)) to 
a=abs(sqrt(Fx**2 + Fy**2)+abs(sqrt(Fgtx**2 + Fgty**2)))

Comment: I think mysterious syntax errors are _always_ caused by the previous line :-)

Comment: Seriously though, Python is not maths. Readability counts. Use spaces, one line per expression, and meaningful variable names.

Comment: What's the point of applying `abs()` to square roots?

Comment: Thank you all! @melpomene you're right, It has no sense! ahaha

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a missing `)` on the previous line:

```
a=abs(sqrt(Fx**2 + Fy**2)+abs(sqrt(Fgtx**2 + Fgty**2))
```

Should be:

```
a=abs(sqrt(Fx**2 + Fy**2))+abs(sqrt(Fgtx**2 + Fgty**2))
```

or

```
a=abs(sqrt(Fx**2 + Fy**2)+abs(sqrt(Fgtx**2 + Fgty**2)))
```